# Disable WebView VideoPlayer in ICS

Tags: android, html, webview, youtube, android-videoview

In ICS, webview loads youtube videos using a built-in html5 videoplayer. 
is there a way to disable that and instead have the embeded youtube player.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to play youtube videos in a webview or launch the youtube app to play the video? Also do you control the source of the webview?

Comment: I am trying to play youtube videos using a webview. I don't know about the second question, I guess not. How can I do that anyway?